# Python Prime "C-number"

Tags: python, numpy

"C-number" is an integer n > 1 such that (b^n)mod n = b for all integers 1

Basically I have to create a program to run through about 2000 integers(1-2000), and have it satisfy the C-number condition, and then also check to see if it is NOT a prime number. I can't seem to get the loop working correctly.
I have a program that creates a list of non primes, and a working program that if I input a number, it will return me that number if it is a c-number, if not I'll get false returned.

I want it to just check numbers 1-2000 rather than just the one number I inputted, and then also check against the list of non prime numbers.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy
def primesfrom2to(n):
""" Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
sieve = numpy.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
for i in xrange(1,int(n**0.5)/3+1):
    if sieve[i]:
        k=3*i+1|1
        sieve[       k*k/3     ::2*k] = False
        sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/3::2*k] = False
    return numpy.r_[2,3,((3*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]

num=range(600)
mylist =primesfrom2to(600)
s = [item for item in num if item not in mylist]
a=[]
d=[]        
from math import *
def numc(n):
    for a in range(1,n):

            c= a**n
        d=c%n       
    if a == d:
        return n
    else:
        return False
print numc(561)
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Which ones? Do you get wrong results? What results do you get and what did you expect instead?

Comment: The question is, how do I make a loop that checks all values 1-2000 for if they're c numbers, and then check against my prime or nonprime number lists? and sth, i'm not getting any errors with this program, i just don't know how to enhance it to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to just fix the indentation (needs fixing in a lot of places):

```
def numc(n):
for a in range(1,n):
    c= a**n
    d=c%n
```

Python is pretty much written through indentation.

Comment: Changing the indentation like that actually gave me an error. The code currently "works" as in all of my parts work as they are written. I'm just very new and not sure how to write a loop for all values 1-2000, rather than just the one I input, and then also compare that against my list of nonprimes

Comment: That's strange. But I think that is your problem in the long run. The primesfrom2to isn't running as a function from what I can see because the indentation is wrong. I could be wrong but did you grab that from a different file and add it here?

Comment: I did grab it from another file, and had to quickly change the indentation here and most likely butchered it. haha

Comment: Then yes, I'd re-work through the code and ensure everything is indented to work how you wish. Then when looping the numbers print them there. When you "return" a function you end the code then and there. You could use "yield" but that's a bit more confusing.

Comment: What would you recommend to put after the if statement? rather than returning a value. Is there something like a "catcher" or a list I can put there to accept all of the true values and create a list of just the cnumbers?

Comment: It'd try looking up the "yield" method of returning a function. It's like xrange(). For a function that "yields" you iterate in in a while loop and each time its is called in the iterator is returns a single value. Do a bit of research into that and it may help. Either that or store them in a list and then return the list at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and even more important: cleanest way is to create two lists, one for prime numbers you found and one for c numbers. Then go through the lists to check which ones are in c numbers and not in prime numbers. Also split the functions for prime and c number in two functions. Something like:

```
prime_numbers = []
c_numbers = []

amount = 2000

for i in xrange(amount):
   if is_prime(i):
      prime_numbers.append(i)

   if is_c_number(i):
      c_numbers.append(i)

for i in xrange(amount):
    if i in c_numbers and (not i in prime_numbers):
        print i
```

Comment: I see what you're going with there, now I have one other question if you can respond. Based off of my code for the cnumbers (numc) how could i set up that loop to create a list with all of the cnumbers, rather than just output a single value for the single value I inputted?

Comment: I'm not sure what numc does, I think it returns n if n is a cnumber and False otherwise (if so you can better have it return false/true). Then you can use is_c_number instead of numc as describe in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, not sure numc() does what you expect -- as written, that if statement will be tested only for the last value of a in the range.  The if statement is not in the for loop block, so the loop will spin through the assignments, and the if statement only goes against the values assigned in the last iteration.  This seems more what you're looking for:

```
def numc(n):
    for a in range(1,n):
        c= a**n
        d=c%n       
        if a != d:
           return False
    return n
```

Here if some a value fails the if test, the function returns False.  If all a values pass it returns true.

Second, neither my draft nor yours returns an array, just an integer or a boolean.  To get an array of values passing, you have to call the function on each item of an array of candidates.

This gives you the output, integer or boolean, for each member of the candidate array:

```
c_values = [numc(i) for i in range(1, 2000)]
```

You can get just the passing values by testing in the loop:

```
    c_values = [numc(i) for i in range(1, 2000) if numc(i)]
```

You can do so without calling numc() twice by nesting the list comprehensions:

```
    c_values = [i for i in [numc(j) for j in range(1, 2000)] if i]
```

That first generates the complete array of output values, then returns only those that are True.

EDIT: You seem confused by the block indentation, or perhaps the two return statements.  Here is another way with one return:

```
def numc(n):
    retval = n
    for a in range(1,n):
        c= a**n
        d=c%n       
        if a != d:
           retval = False # reset return value
           break   # halt the loop
    return retval
```

Here the default return value is << n >>, to be reset within the << for >>loop if cnumber conditionality is violated by some value of << a >>.  In which case, << break >> halts the loop (though here it needn't.)  The function just returns whatever << retval >> happens to be when the return statment is reached.

My initial draft had the same effect, but there the for loop was interrupted / 'broken' by the << return False >> statement -- which also there interrupted the function, preventing it from reaching the << return n >>.  If that statement weren't reached, ie no << a >> violated conditionality, the function would reach and execute << return n >>.  If a function has two return statements, it will only execute the first one reached, and all code after that will be ignored.

Comment: Much appreciated! I got it to work exactly how I wanted. I do have one question thought if oyu don't mind answering. How exactly does that first loop of numc(n) work that you made? I'm slightly confused about your second return, and what it's in reference to